# Replacing null values by average of values grouped by concatenated categories in Teradata

Tags: group-by, average, teradata, missing-data, imputation

Suppose that I have a lot of NULL values (missing values) in a column named 'score'. I want to replace them by a specific average not from all the values of the column 'score' but by groups that I built with a crosscategory from two concatenated categories:

This kind of query works for getting averages by groups:

```
SELECT
category1 || ' > ' || category2 AS crosscategory,
ROUND(CAST(AVG(score) AS FLOAT), 2) AS score_avg
FROM DatabaseName.TableName
GROUP BY crosscategory
ORDER BY score_avg;
```

This one works to replace NULL values by a constant:

```
SELECT
NVL(score, 0) AS score_without_missing_values
FROM DatabaseName.TableName
```

The problem that I cannot solve now is how to articulate the replacement of NULL values with a constant here the averages computed with the functions AVG and  GROUP BY.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want a *Group Average*:

```
SELECT
   t.*,
   coalesce(score, AVG(score) OVER (PARTITION BY category1, category2)) AS score_avg
FROM DatabaseName.TableName AS t
```

I removed the ROUND/CAST, because AVG returns FLOAT by default and ROUND in probably not needed (if you need it, you might better cast to a DECIMAL).

Comment: I received a 2646 error : No more spool space

Comment: In outputs, I would prefer to keep this also : category1 || ' > ' || category2 AS crosscategory

Comment: Of course, you can keep `category1 || ' > ' || category2 AS crosscategory`. Regarding *no more spool space*: what's the number of rows and the datatype of those categories? You could also try to join back your group averages, but this might spool out, too.

Comment: There are 14580 rows with the score and its datatype is integer. The categories have datatype VARCHAR.

Comment: What size of the VarChar? 14580 rows? That's not a lot, does your query run without adding the average?